# How to create Dynamic Cascading Menus in windows explorer.exe?

Tags: windows, contextmenu

i know how to create Static Cascading Menus from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to--create-cascading-menus-with-the-subcommands-registry-entry

now i want to create Dynamic Cascading Menus that use commands in */shellex/ContextMenuHandlers ,

how to do it ?
thanks!

link about "Dynamic":
Customizing a Shortcut Menu Using Dynamic Verbs - Win32 apps | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shortcut-menu-using-dynamic-verbs

Answer (score 0):

In your `IContextMenu` implementation you are handed a `HMENU` during the query, you may use the normal WinAPI menu functions to add submenus in whatever hierarchy you want.

See also:

- [How to Implement the IContextMenu Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-implement-the-icontextmenu-interface)
- [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions: Part I](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

Comment: thanks for response!  i can not write C++/C code  so i hope to realize it by changing window registry, is it possible ?

Comment: How do you expect to have dynamic menus without code? Only static is possible with the registry for cascading menus.

Comment: ok, i decide to give up when i see  "Only static is possible with the registry for cascading menus"  . are there third-party tools can do it ? thanks!